# Export Data From SQLPro for MSSQL in Mac to R

Tags: sql-server, r, macos

I am using the SQLPro for MSSQL tool on my MAC. I would like to take the table built by my query there and either dump into a csv (I could copy and paste but am looking for a simpler option) or preferably R for further analysis.

I have seen several methods that work in other operating systems or other SQL tools, but none specific to my needs. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

If you control-click on the table name, it will bring up a contextual menu that will allow you to export the table as a CSV.